# how to filter dropdown values based on the value of other dropdown in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have 2 models main_category and sub_category, in the sub_category model, it has a name and Foreign key of the main_category it belongs to. and I have 3rd model which is 'record' and it has main_category and sub_category as a Foreign key. what I need is when selecting the main category from the drop-down in the 'record' form it should filter the values in the sub_category dropdown so that it shows only the values that have the selected main category

here are the models

```
class MainCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
activity_status = models.BooleanField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
main_category = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
activity_status = models.BooleanField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Record(models.Model):
RECORD_TYPES = [
    ('income', 'Income'),
    ('expense', 'Expense'),
    ('transfer', 'Transfer'),
]

DELETED_CATEGORY = 'Deleted category'

date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
category = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.SET(DELETED_CATEGORY), default=1)
subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.SET(DELETED_CATEGORY))
type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=RECORD_TYPES)
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
transfer_ops = models.ForeignKey(TransferOperation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
activity_status = models.BooleanField()

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.date} - {self.type}: {self.amount}"
```

and here is the view

```
class CreateRecordView(CreateView):
model = Record
form_class = RecordForm
template_name = 'create_record.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['subcategory'].queryset = SubCategory.objects.none()

    category_id = self.request.POST.get('category') or self.request.GET.get('category')
    if category_id:
        form.fields['subcategory'].queryset = SubCategory.objects.filter(main_category_id=category_id)

    return form
```

---

I tried javascript solution but it doesn't work, this is what I did

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Create Record</h2>
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id_category">Category</label>
  {{ form.category }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id_subcategory">Subcategory</label>
  <select name="subcategory" id="id_subcategory" class="form- 
control">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
      <option value="{{ subcategory.pk }}" data-category="{{ 
subcategory.main_category.pk }}">{{ subcategory.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>

<script src="C:\Users\rere\PycharmProjects\bocket\js\
filter_subcategories.js"> 
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var subcategorySelect = $('#id_subcategory');
var subcategoryOptions = subcategorySelect.find('option');

$('#id_category').change(function() {
var selectedCategoryId = $(this).val();

// Reset subcategory options
subcategorySelect.val('');
subcategoryOptions.hide();

// Show subcategories corresponding to the selected category
subcategoryOptions.filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('category') == selectedCategoryId;
}).show();
});
});
```

Comment: One way is to use ajax request,  when an option is selected in the first drop-down  an ajax request send to the server and the response will be used to fill the options in the second drop-down

Comment: Generally what you already have in `CreateRecordView` should do the trick. If you want realtime filtering on the frontend, aka no refresh, you're going to have to to add JavaScript that will manually hide+show the correct Options inside the subcategory Select field.

Comment: @NealiumI tried to apply the Java script solution but it doesn't work, I added my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already created a mini project on your requirement you can check the code from this github repo [here](https://github.com/Mahammadhusain/depend.git)

#### Browser Output

[image]